# Can't attach to GNU Screen - not showing in list but still running

Tags: gnu-screen

I have screen running but it doesn't show in a list and it won't allow me to attach it.

```
$ screen -ls                                                          
(08-21 12:38:23)  No Sockets found in /tmp/uscreens/S-myusername.
```

But listing process will show it's there:

```
$ ps axf
18474 ?        Ss     2:42 SCREEN -dR
 2589 pts/0    Ss     2:18  \_ /bin/zsh
21978 pts/0    S+     0:00  |   \_ ssh xyz.asdf.qwer.com
 6231 pts/6    Ss+    0:00  \_ /bin/zsh
 6265 pts/7    Ss     0:00  \_ /bin/zsh
29523 pts/7    S+     0:00  |   \_ vim webapp/js/xyz/asdf.js
15643 pts/8    Ss     0:02  \_ /bin/zsh
29306 pts/8    S+     0:00  |   \_ vim webapp/js/common/xyz/qwer.js
29467 pts/4    Ss+    0:00  \_ /bin/zsh
29556 pts/9    Ss+    0:00  \_ /bin/zsh
15465 pts/1    Ss+    0:22  \_ /bin/zsh
32391 pts/10   Ss+    0:00  \_ /bin/zsh
22853 pts/2    Ss+    0:00  \_ /bin/zsh
```

How can I re-attach to this screen?

Screen version:

```
$ screen --version
(08-21 12:45:53)Screen version 4.01.00devel (FAU) 2-May-06
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that I have 2 versions of screen on my $PATH. One version is looking for socket in `/tmp/uscreens/S-myusername` other in `/var/run/screen/S-myusername`.

I've did some changes to $PATH and the incorrect version was executed. I found missing file in `/var/run/screen/S-myusername` and solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The program is telling you there are no sockets.  Either you accidentally deleted the socket (or the directory holding it), or you are running as a different user.